# Reading table in pdf using java

Tags: java

I want to read a table in an existing pdf file using java. I am able to read text from pdf using below code (apache pdfBox):

```
File file=new File("ReadTest.pdf");
PDDocument pdfDocument = PDDocument.load(file);     
System.out.println("PDF loaded");
PDFTextStripperByArea stripper = new PDFTextStripperByArea();
stripper.setSortByPosition(true);
PDFTextStripper  pdfStripper=new PDFTextStripper();
pdfStripper.setSortByPosition(true);
String text=pdfStripper.getText(pdfDocument);
```

First I want to detect from where the table data start in the given pdf  then read table data (while table row and column are unknown).

Answer (score 1):

I found your answer in this site https://dzone.com/articles/traprange-method-extract-table...

In my work, I process text chunks directly by using TextPosition objects. For each text chunk in PDF file, it returns a text element with following attributes:

x: horizontal distance from the left of the page///
y: vertical distance from the top border of the page///
maxX: equals x + width of the text chunk///
maxY: equals y+ height of the text chunk
for example look at this image
https://github.com/thoqbk/traprange/blob/master/_Docs/textposition-rectangle.png